# Stored procedure / bulk insert difficulties

Tags: sql-server

I am working on writing some very simple stored procedures that take a CSV and import them into a database. However, I have encountered a syntax error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near 'FIELDTERMINATOR'.

My SQL is very simple so I am not sure why I am getting this error:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[addEmployees]
    @filePath NVARCHAR(150)
AS
    declare @sql varchar(max)
    select @sql = 'BULK INSERT dbo.insuranceMidAm.employees FROM " ';
    select @sql = @sql + @filePath;
    select @sql = @sql + ' " WITH(
                                  FIRSTROW = 2
                                  FIELDTERMINATOR = ",",
                                  ROWTERMINATOR = "\n"
                                 )';

    exec(@sql)
```

AND

```
EXEC dbo.addEmployees 'TEST_2016_employees.txt'
```

I have tried various combinations of quotes and punctuation, but keep getting an error. What might the source be?

Thanks!

Comment: You missed comma after `FIRSTROW = 2`

Comment: Thanks, but even when I add that, I receive the following: Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: use `print @sql` instead of `exec` and see what is wrong with your code. For example spaces `" '` and `' "`.

Comment: Looks like you have double quotes in your strings there.  Those need to be replaced with 2 single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your double-quotes around the file, `FIELDTERMINATOR` and `ROWTERMINATOR` should be single quotes (double-them up since you're in dynamic SQL):

```
FROM '' ';
select @sql = @sql + @filePath;
select @sql = @sql + ' '' WITH(
            FIRSTROW = 2
            FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
            ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
        )';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes are incorrect, should be two ' next to each other instead of ". You are also missing a comma after the 2.

```
FROM '' ';
select @sql = @sql + @filePath;
select @sql = @sql + ' '' WITH(
            FIRSTROW = 2,
            FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
            ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
        )';
```